# React Native Android needs to target API level 29 before November 2, 2020

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

As per the new Google Play policy, all apps must target at least Android 10 (API 29) before November 2, 2020.

More info: https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies

React Native is targeting API 28 as of today(v0.63), are there any plans to update the target SDK version?

Comment: Actually RN v63.0 supports sdk version 29. Look at this [changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: @firats in the changelog, there is nothing about bumping `targetSdk` to 29. There is only "Bump Android build-tools to 29.0.2, compileSdk to 29" but this is different

Comment: @matusalem well.. it supports anyway. [Here is the main issue about the topic](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29496#issuecomment-664511313)

Comment: @firats, ok you are right. After I init a new RN project, I noticed `targetSdk=29` in build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Open android/build.gradle in your React Native project and change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values to 29.

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.5"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
}
}
```

**Then go Android Studio and Run "Sync Project with File System" (File > Sync Project with Gradle Files).**

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to upgrade your React Native version. You can see the instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading).

A simple cli upgrade did the trick for me:

```
npx react-native upgrade
```